# Exporting and module exporting in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

I have a file on main root as

> test_file.js

Following is the code inside it

```
var config = require('config');
var Ctrl = require('./Controllers');
var port = process.env.PORT || config.get("PORT") || 3000;
var cors = require('cors');
var express = require('express');  
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();

app.use(cors());

app.use(router);
var server = require('http').createServer(app); 

var io = require('socket.io')(server, {'pingInterval': 4000, 'pingTimeout': 6000});

io.on('connection', Ctrl.connection);

console.log("Opening at port " + port);
server.listen(port, function () {
});

module.exports = router;
require('./Routes')();
```

I have another file in path

> /Controllers/index.js

i want to pass out `io` to index.js too, here is its code

```
    var Promise = require('q').Promise;
    var config  = require('config');
    var mysql   = require('mysql');

/// I want to get var io = require('../test_file.js');

    /**Initialization socket connection */
    exports.connection = function (socket) {
        if (!(socket.handshake.query.accountType != null && socket.handshake.query.id != null && socket.handshake.query.accessKey != null
            && socket.handshake.query.id > 0)) {
            socket.disconnect();
            return;
        }
```

Now i am confused about module.exports and exports, my module.exports is already passing out to another file, i want to add another variable i-e `io` and pass it to controllers file. How can i do that

In respond to the query,

```
app.use(router);
var server = require('http').createServer(app); 

var io = require('socket.io')(server, {'pingInterval': 4000, 'pingTimeout': 6000});
module.exports = {
  router: router,
  io: io
};

io.on('connection', Ctrl.connection);

console.log("Opening at port " + port);
server.listen(port, function () {
});

require('./Routes')();
```

In Controllers/index.js

```
var Promise = require('q').Promise;
var config  = require('config');
var mysql   = require('mysql');

var Driver  = require('./driver');
var User    = require('./user');

var io = require('../test_file.js').io;
console.log("logging");
console.log(io);
```

the result is `{} for io`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `exports` is just `module.exports's` little helper. Your module returns `module.exports` to the caller ultimately, `not exports`. All exports does is collect properties and attach them to `module.exports` IF `module.exports` doesn't have something on it already. If there's something attached to module.exports already, everything on exports is ignored.

you can pass both as the object

```
 module.exports = {
  router: router,
  io: io
};
```

[Please refer this doc for more explanation](http://www.hacksparrow.com/node-js-exports-vs-module-exports.html)

**Edit**

Access object via module.exports

`file.js`

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('respond with a resource');
});

module.exports = {router:router};
```

Acess it with

```
var router=require('./file').router
   OR

var router=require('./file');

router.router
```

Comment: i have done that but how can i access var router = require('../test_file.js').router; is not working

Comment: Actually i dont have any code in router to check so i am just doing logging for io, i edited my code , check out what could be wrong